# How I can get guild.id

Tags: discord.js

I'm making a team that should create a category with the appropriate rights, but I need some kind of guild id. how can I get the guild server id through the user who wrote this command

```js
    if (message.channel.type === "text" && message.guild && message.guild.ownerID == message.author.id) {
        if (content.startsWith("*install")) {
            let server = message.guild.id[guild.id];
            guild1.createChannel('new-category', {
                type: 'category',
                permissionsOverwrites: [{
                  id: guild.id,
                  deny: ['MANAGE_MESSAGES'],
                  allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES']
                }]
              })
                .then(console.log)
                .catch(console.error);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `message.guild.id`

```js
if (message.channel.type === "text" && message.guild && message.guild.ownerID == message.author.id) {
        if (content.startsWith("*install")) {
            
            guild1.createChannel('new-category', {
                type: 'category',
                permissionsOverwrites: [{
                  id: message.guild.id,
                  deny: ['MANAGE_MESSAGES'],
                  allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES']
                }]
              })
                .then(console.log)
                .catch(console.error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: no. error
https://hastebin.com/aqezucasul.coffeescript

Comment: How are you using `server`? Why are you using`message.guild.id[guild.id]`?

Comment: No way. I do not know

Comment: Remove `server` like I did in my edited answer if you're not using it